# Hibernate not saving ManyToOne when target is composite key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, composite-key

Hibernate does not seem to be updating an FK reference when the object of that association is a composite key.

The transaction succeeds (no error, no stack trace), but there is no update statement generated (I have hibernate logging enabled).

I have tried all manner of cascade annotations (no cascade, ALL, PERSIST, even SAVE_UPDATE) without any change to the symptoms. This no-update symptom exists both from an on-line OpenXava screen as well as from custom Java code (in an OpenXava action).

The application database has requirements to allow external uploads to tables, so I have been told that switching to system-assigned keys is not an option they are willing to pursue.

The owning association (currently without any cascade setting):

```
  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,optional=false)
  @Required
  @JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="programID",referencedColumnName="programID",nullable=false,unique=false,insertable=false,updatable=false),
    @JoinColumn(name="projectID",referencedColumnName="projectID",nullable=false,unique=false,insertable=false,updatable=false)
  })
  @DescriptionsList(descriptionProperties="parentProgram.programName,projectName")
  @ReferenceView("reference")
  private Project associatedProject;
```

The inverse association:

```
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="associatedProject",fetch=FetchType.LAZY) //No cascade allowed
  @ReadOnly
  private Set<Asset> assets = new HashSet<Asset>();
```

Does anyone know if there is an open Hibernate bug on this? I have not been able to find any using Google search, but perhaps someone has first-hand experience.

Thanks, 
Roy.

EDIT: As a work-around, I tried to write my own HQL update.

```
update Asset set associatedProject = :ap where assetKey = :key
```

That fails on an obtuse Hibernate syntax error `unexpected AST node: AND` while processing the SET clause.

```
update Asset set associatedProject.projectId = :projId, associatedProject.parentProgram = :pgm where assetKey = :key
```

That generated `update Asset cross join  set projectID=?, programID=? where assetKey=?` and then failed on invalid syntax at "cross"

However, doing my own SQL update works.

**Does anyone have a better work-around? Or any further thoughts on the root problem?**

In my opinion, this still points to a Hibernate bug (of course it's a bug -- you can't just **skip** an update without any errors or messages) with composite key handling.

Comment: I haven't looked closely at what you did, but I doubt it's a hibernate bug (hibernate is way mature).

Comment: @Robert in my experience, not so much. Most of the composite key support is poorly documented at best and doesn't work exactly as advertised (although thus far there seem to be work-arounds for most problems).

Comment: @Brian `programID/projectID` is the composite key for Project entity. `programID` is the single key for Program entity. A Program has many Projects. An Asset (the context of my quoted code) is associated with a specific Project (implemented as a 2-column FK on the Asset table), but can be transferred from one Project to another. This is the cause of the symptom -- when changing the association from one Project to another, Hibernate does not persist the changed `associatedProject` value.

Comment: [I deleted my earlier comment as it was not helpful.] Maybe your problem is that you have marked your `@JoinColumn`s "read only" (i.e. `insertable=false,updatable=false`)?

Comment: @Brian, you are probably correct that this is the source of the failure. However, I can't change them to `true` because then it generates an exception: `org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.xyz.Asset column: projectID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")` because they are parent and child, and therefore share keys.

Comment: Ahhh - so my earlier, deleted comment, might be relevant - you are probably using a "derived identity". You need to show more code; in particular, the primary key fields for Asset, Project, and Project. I will post a suggestion in the answers....

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I am currently facing it!

Comment: @Crystian182 We didn't. Shortly after this thread a decision was made to go in another direction.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. It is disappointing that an ORM like Hibernate has this strange problem!

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate does not save the relationship because you say it that doesn't save it. Just remove the insertable=false,updatable=false from your two @JoinColumn.

Comment: This doesn't work because it generates a Hibernate mapping exception complaining about a repeated column (see my comment to Brian above). Furthermore, Hibernate doesn't allow mix & match of true & false on the same mapping (which is what would be required for proper composite key FK reference support).

Comment: JPA does not allow to map a relationship and a column against the same column without the insertable=false, updatable=true. You have to modify the plain properties from the setter of the relationship. Look at Carrier.java of OpenXavaTest project

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start on how you might use "derived identity" to map your primary keys, and this might help. I'm just guessing at your model. But it's a start....

```
@Entity
public class Program {
    @Id
    int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="program")
    Set<Project> projects;

    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class ProjectID {
    int projectID;
    int programID; // corresponds to the type of Program's primary key

    ...
}

@Entity
public class Project {
    @EmbeddedId
    ProjectID id;

    @MapsId("programID") // maps 'programID' attribute of embedded ID
    @ManyToOne
    Program program;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="associatedProject", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    Set<Asset> assets;

    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class AssetID {
    int assetID;
    ProjectID projectID; // corresponds to the type of Project's primary key

    ...
}

@Entity
public class Asset {
    @EmbeddedId
    AssetID id;

    @MapsId("projectID") // maps 'projectID' attribute of embedded ID
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
    Project associatedProject;

    ...
}
```

Derived identities are discussed in the JPA 2.1 spec, section 2.4.1.

Comment: OK, I went down the @EmbeddedId path once before, but let's do it again for the sake of this discussion. Some clarifications on the model -- Program and Project are pretty good as is. However, there is a third level named Wave that is a 0:M direct descendant of Project, composite key is programID,projectID,WaveID. In my experience, this is where Hibernate starts to display its composite key limitations, at the third level. Then, Asset (key is just assetID) has a mandatory FK to Project and an optional FK to Wave.